# runWithDocumentContext:passing data back to the xpage

Tags: xpages

I was playing around with run With Document Context almost the whole day. Maybe someone can help to find me a feasible solution.

If i run the agent in before page load / before render response / query Open Document event i am able to pass values back to the xpage without saving the document. I tried also to save the document but it didnt help.

Beside these two events i didn't find a way to call the agent and bring the values from the lotus notes agent back. Can anybody think of an event that would work?

Comment: Do you mean "unable" in paragraph 2 where you say "able"?

Comment: no. i am able to pass values back. but these events dont help me because they are triggered only in the beginning. i would need them on a partial or full refresh

Comment: I would strongly suggest you not try to do all this with agents.  Write the code you need in SSJS if at all possible (oh Java if available).  The app will perform MUCH better overall.  You should be able to pass to an Agent of course - but doing so during partial refreshes and all that?  That's just scary sounding...

Comment: Sorry but the script library is really huge. Calling the agent during partial refresh works fine. The only problem that i have is bringing the data back to the xpage. Even if i save the document i have to reload the whole xpage. Any suggestions on a event i can use.

Comment: just a thought: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.html#restoreWrappedDocument() if you saved the backend doc. But I recommend to call the agent with dummy doc and reaply its items after the call to datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Calling an agent does work from anywhere you can call SSJS. Some [considerations are on my blog](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SF7AH).

However there is one big, big caveat: when you try to use a document (saved or unsaved) that is bound to a datasource in your current XPage, then the values in the datasource will overwrite the changes in the backend document. This could be your issue?

As David suggests: use SSJS & Java. It is less work than you might fear and you can pay down some technical debt

Comment: Sorry but rewritting is not an option as the scriptlibraries are huge. I know that i can call an agent everywhere but if i change fields in the agent that i also have in the xpage it seems like they are not coming back. Only if i call the agent in the mentioned events i can see the values coming back to the xpage. Any suggestions how to bring values back to an xpage if i call the agent in a button

Comment: They are coming back, but are overwritten by the data binding. So you could: create a new document, no need to save. Copy all items. Run your agent and inspect what is coming back. And you will regret not looking at conversion of LotusScript to refactored Java earlier

Comment: So the question would be how can you do a partial refresh and get values from the backend document back without sending the values coming through the data binding.

Comment: OK i found something that works. I can manipulate the document in the backend. Save it. And do a JS refresh of the whole page. That will bring the values back from the backend document. Not nice but it works

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a new Domino document, put the fields on it that you want to send, call your agent, and then get back those fields. Then populate whatever you need to on the XPage (getComponent("name").setValue(value).

There is no need to save this temporary document and it will just end up going away when your code runs.